# Add columns into a csv file

Tags: cmd

I'm interested in how I can get the word between brackets () from the first column and add it to the extra column in the csv file. and to do this in cmd.

my current table looks like this and I would like to add the serial number of the device that is in the brackets in the first column to the end in a separate column

So my table looks like this

`Name                                               Size
 Delovno poročilo - 2018082701 (X14E680262).xlsx    19965`

but i want the serial number betwen bracket to add in anotehr column like this

`Name                                               Size   Serial Number
 Delovno poročilo - 2018082701 (X14E680262).xlsx    19965  X14E680262`

Now i have code writen in .cmd file can i do this?

Comment: Can you demonstrate *any* effort at even *trying* to solve this yourself?

Comment: Personally I won't follow links to sites unknown to me, I suggest you either upload your picture to imgur through the picture button or preferably post data as text and format with pre tags or indent 4 spaces

Comment: i update my post there is no link to image anymore

Comment: i see a lot of code where can extract some string or add custom column to csv but im not so expert with code language and i dont find anywhere code where do what i want. so i please for help who know how to do this